# "The 'html' element is not declared." in XmlValidatingReader

Tags: c#, wcf, doctype, xmlreader

I have this html doc:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form class="Form" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" id="Form" method="post">
//form body
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is stack trace:

> at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReaderImpl.ValidationEventHandling.System.Xml.IValidationEventHandling.SendEvent(Exception exception, XmlSeverityType severity)
>      at System.Xml.Schema.BaseValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String arg)
>      at System.Xml.Schema.DtdValidator.ProcessElement()
>      at System.Xml.Schema.DtdValidator.Validate()
>      at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReaderImpl.Read()
>      at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion version, String action, XmlDictionaryReader body)
>      at Renault.LMT.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ServerMessageFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)

Code, error occurs in the last line:

```
MemoryStream MemoryStreamm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((MessageBody)));
MemoryStreamm.Position = 0;
XmlReaderSettings settingsReader = new XmlReaderSettings();
settingsReader.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
settingsReader.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
settingsReader.XmlResolver = null;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(MemoryStreamm, settingsReader);

MessageResponse = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, string.Format("ServiceModel/ILMTService/{0}", Operation), reader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver.aspx , it doesn't look like a good idea to set the XmlResolver to null. It's likely that the DTD can't be loaded so it can't match any element, the first of which is `html`.

I strongly recommend that you store a copy of the DTD locally, and implement an XmtResolver that, when the DTD is requested, returns that local copy. You should always do this for DTDs and XML Schemas because many servers providing these files severely throttle the number of requests from any one location.